# Poor performance with rsync on Windows

Tags: windows, rsync

I've just set up file synchronization between a Windows 2000 Server and a Windows 2003 Server using [cwrsync](http://www.itefix.no/i2/node/10650), a windows compile of rsync. It was easy to setup and seems to work well but I am seeing a problem with speed, the client does not seem to be able to top 130 Kb/s despite the network being capable of delivering 1 Mb/s over FTP. Anyone else experienced this and found a solution?

I currently use a workaround where I run three rsync processes in parallell to the same server. All three processes hit about 130 Kb/s.

Comment: What is the upload speed of the receiving server rated at?

Comment: Upload should be 8 Mbit/s. I can get around 800 KB/s sending to the server using FTP.

Answer (score 1):

I use rsync on loads of sites, but only with ADSL 440Kbps and 800Kbps upload speeds. However on those lines I've found it manages to use about 80% of the bandwidth. I assume the rest is down to latency and the protocol overhead.

For what it's worth, while CWRsync is a simple installation it's actually very easy to roll your own rsync transfers, and you get the very latest Cygwin build of rsync. See http://www.ratsauce.co.uk/notablog/UsingRsync.asp for my version of a walkthrough.

JR

Answer (score 0):

I had a speed issue with Unison (another file sync program) on Windows when I was using freeSSHd. A switch to CopSSH solved the issue.

Conveniently, CopSSH is built by the same people as cwRsync, so it is easy to match Cygwin versions between them and copy over `rsync.exe` from the cwRsync installation directory to `/usr/bin` in CopSSH — works like charm.